# How to structure Vuex modules in VueJS project?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vuex

I have installed Vuex in VueJS project and now I want to have the following structure: to have a global "state" (along with "getters", "actions" and "mutations") and to have a few other "modules", where each module will have it's own "state", "getters", "actions" and "mutations". So I'm not sure how the structure should look like. Is this a good approach for this purpose:

[image]

where in scripts for "actions", "getters" and "mutations" I'm simply exporting the functions and here is the content of the other files:

**root/store/modules/exampleModule/store.js**:

```
import * as actions from './actions';
import * as getters from './getters';
import * as mutations from './mutations';

const state = {

}

export default {        
    state,
    getters,
    actions,
    mutations
}
```

**root/store/store.js:**

```
import * as actions from './actions';
import * as getters from './getters';
import * as mutations from './mutations';

// initial state
const state = {

}

export default {        
    state,
    getters,
    actions,
    mutations
}
```

**root/store/index.js:**

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import Vuex from 'vuex';
import exampleModule from './modules/exampleModule/store.js';
import globalStore from './store';

Vue.use(Vuex);
const debug = process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production';

export default new Vuex.Store({
  globalStore,
  modules: {
    exampleModule
  },
  strict: debug
})
```

Comment: what's the question exactly? This approach will work fine and is scalable. It may be a bit too verbose depending on how you size your modules (most of the time, one file per module should be fine in terms of length), but using Vuex's modularization feature is a very good way to structure state.

Comment: @GeorgGrab I'm not sure about the part inside the new **Vuex.Store({ ... })** if it's a good practise to add the globalStore as it is above, considering the way it was exported in the global store.js script.

Comment: you may want something like `...globalStore` .. but for me this is confusing, in 2 month you will not remember why you split up the root-store into 2 files